# is it possible to access internal load balancer across regions

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I setup a load balancer in east region and then tried to access it by ip in the central region.   Accessing the LB from the central region hangs like the packets are dropped.   I was successful in accessing the VM that is in the LB's instance group directly so it does appear that it is LB specific.

I tried updating the routes and firewall, but that appeared to already be correct and didn't have an affect.

setting up new virtual machines just to route traffic to the instance group seems very error prone.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible.

the load balancing they use doesn't require a server and only works within a single region.